# Reset links after refresh the page CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with CSS selector `:visited`. I need that after updating the page, the links appear as if you had never visited them, but I don't know how I can reset them.

I want to create a list of links, after clicking on them, they change the color, and with this you can have control of the list, but, after finishing with all the links, refresh the page and start again, with all the default links

Comment: some code please!!!!

Comment: Add some code samples. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EMiDU you have a substantial edit pending. Where'd you get that code from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague EMiDU answered partially correct, because he was selecting only the first aHref from that page. The code bellow applies to all hrefs in a page.

Please read everything, including the comments so you can understand it better.

```js
// Select all hrefs in the page
var all_hrefs = document.querySelectorAll("a");

// For each a[href] add an eventListener on "click" event, and add "visited" class to it
//
// :visited - selector is controlled by browser and you
// .visited - class selector is controlled only by you
//
all_hrefs.forEach(function(single_href) {

  single_href.addEventListener('click', function(){
    
    // Mark link as visited
    // Please note the change I've done to CSS too
    // I replaced :visted with .visited
    this.classList.add('visited');
    
  })
});
```

```css
.icon{
    background-color: #FF5722;
    display: inline-block;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    padding: var(--padding);
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0.8em;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
.icon:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #FF6922;
    /*Shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 23px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 23px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 23px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.img{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: var(--icon);
}
.txt{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: var(--txt);
}
a:link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
a.visited > p{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    <a href="https://www.dea.gov/fugitives/all" target="_blank">
        <i class="fas fa-fingerprint img"></i>
        <p class="txt">DEA</p>
    </a>
</div>

<br />
Please note that when you click on this link, it is StackOverflow snippet that does not load your link. Copy the JavaScript code into &lt;script&gt; tags and replace <b>:visited</b> selector in CSS with <b>.visited</b> then test the code. It will work as expected! :)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't control `:visited` behaviour since it is controlled by browser. Unless you modify link `href`, however it seems to be overcomplicated.

You can solve your problem with simple CSS and JavaScript, instead of using `:visited` pseudoclass, by simply adding class to clicked links. After refreshing the page, classes would disappear.

**CSS**

```
...

a.clicked > p {
    color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if ( ! this.classList.contains('clicked')) {
        this.classList.add('clicked');
    }
});
```